# Strange database structure

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm taking a quick look at a SQL Server database for a web application.
The first thing I notice is that out of the 200-300 tables there are only 2 tables with a primary key and they are composite keys.  No other indexes anywhere.  Even the "members" tables have no indexed keys.  There is also no use of foreign keys anywhere.
Should I be worried?
Is there a good explanation for why such a structure might be desirable?

Comment: Look at the bright side: you'll come back here at SO with questions for years and years, since nothing will work ;)

Answer (score 8):

**Y E S ! !**  you should be worried......

To quote a SQL guru:

> *if it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table*

Any table **ought to have** a primary key - only a primary key ensures any given row can be uniquely identified (and operated on - doing whatever you need to do to it).

To make matters worse, in SQL Server, tables without a clustering key (which the primary key is, by default) are called *heaps* and those have terribly bad performance characteristics. The *Queen of Indexing* - Kimberly Tripp - nicely shows all the bad things about heaps in her blog post [The Clustered Index Debate Continues!](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) - read it, and live it :-)

And **not having any foreign keys** borders on absolute recklessness - any DB developers that knowingly avoid foreign keys ought to be taken out and shot... this is **THE** main reason to even have a relational database - the ability to **enforce data consistency and data integrity**.

> *shaking head in disbelief - yet again....*

Comment: unless, of course, the tables are all _isolated_ fact tables, imported from some datawarehouse. The odds of that being... close to zero of course, you get my +1

Comment: @sehe: true - a datawarehouse is a bit different (I'm an OLTP developer - and the OP's question doesn't seem to refer to a DWH, either), and a temporary staging table even in a OLTP database can also be without PK - but those are **extremely rare** edge cases in an OLTP environment - not the 95% case as here....

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the Database architect designer ... your setup is good and bad.

I'll give you an example of a **CRM application** called [SuperOffice](http://www.superoffice.com/), their SQL database has a lot of tables, but none has PK or FK and there is no field that has auto-number, id's are given by a conceptual table that holds the table entity id and last created id.

[image]

And it's extremely fast!

So I wouldn't worry to much, thought I would ask why just for the curiosity point, the same I did to SuperOffice folks :)

Comment: and what did the SuperOffice folks say as I can't think of any reason why you'd use an RDBMS but not use keys, FKs and indexes? I bet it's fast if the tables are small, but how is it scalable when the tables grow and require indexing?

Comment: to be honest, I have seen my share of the CRM5 database scheme some years back, and to say it was extremely fast is not accurate. It isn't slow. In fact, that is gonna be down to the fact that they simply avoid the database for any work. And _that_ shows in the UI (it is, shall we say, less than flexible). It has neat sides, though

Comment: @sehe We have some customers with more than 350.000 clients... so imagine the Sales table... and it's fast. It's the **Netserver SDK** that slows everything down as it does all those checks for resources access authentication, matrix rules, etc before hand over the data... DB itself, even without indexing, it's fast when we know how to look up the data ... witch sometimes need some extra queries :)

Comment: @balexandre: oh the memories. `Sentries` they were called. It was a good design though. It just was a bit complicated